# The Android libstreaming is broadcasting audio without video to server?

Tags: java, android, libstreaming

We are using Example 3 from this URL to broadcast streaming from Android camera device to server , we change code only to connect with our server not with Wowza server but the video is not arrive to server or by another meaning the input stream file is arriving empty to server for video but the audio is arriving perfectly , sometimes the connection with server is lost after some seconds , How we can know if this problem from server side or from client (code) side , We are using the same code here with change ip address and port number of our server.

https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

The encoding process may be effect in this case?

Session Builder

```
public class SessionBuilder {

public final static String TAG = "SessionBuilder";

/** Can be used with {@link #setVideoEncoder}. */
public final static int VIDEO_NONE = 0;

/** Can be used with {@link #setVideoEncoder}. */
public final static int VIDEO_H264 = 1;

/** Can be used with {@link #setVideoEncoder}. */
public final static int VIDEO_H263 = 2;

/** Can be used with {@link #setAudioEncoder}. */
public final static int AUDIO_NONE = 0;

/** Can be used with {@link #setAudioEncoder}. */
public final static int AUDIO_AMRNB = 3;

/** Can be used with {@link #setAudioEncoder}. */
public final static int AUDIO_AAC = 5;

// Default configuration
private VideoQuality mVideoQuality = VideoQuality.DEFAULT_VIDEO_QUALITY;
private AudioQuality mAudioQuality = AudioQuality.DEFAULT_AUDIO_QUALITY;
private Context mContext;
private int mVideoEncoder = VIDEO_H263; 
private int mAudioEncoder = AUDIO_AMRNB;
private int mCamera = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
private int mTimeToLive = 64;
private int mOrientation = 0;
private boolean mFlash = false;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView = null;
private String mOrigin = null;
private String mDestination = null;
private Session.Callback mCallback = null;

// Removes the default public constructor
private SessionBuilder() {}

// The SessionManager implements the singleton pattern
private static volatile SessionBuilder sInstance = null; 

/**
 * Returns a reference to the {@link SessionBuilder}.
 * @return The reference to the {@link SessionBuilder}
 */
public final static SessionBuilder getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (SessionBuilder.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                SessionBuilder.sInstance = new SessionBuilder();
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}   

/**
 * Creates a new {@link Session}.
 * @return The new Session
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public Session build() {
    Session session;

    session = new Session();
    session.setOrigin(mOrigin);
    session.setDestination(mDestination);
    session.setTimeToLive(mTimeToLive);
    session.setCallback(mCallback);

    switch (mAudioEncoder) {
    case AUDIO_AAC:
        AACStream stream = new AACStream();
        session.addAudioTrack(stream);
        if (mContext!=null) 
            stream.setPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext));
        break;
    case AUDIO_AMRNB:
        session.addAudioTrack(new AMRNBStream());
        break;
    }

    switch (mVideoEncoder) {
    case VIDEO_H263:
        session.addVideoTrack(new H263Stream(mCamera));
        break;
    case VIDEO_H264:
        H264Stream stream = new H264Stream(mCamera);
        if (mContext!=null) 
            stream.setPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext));
        session.addVideoTrack(stream);
        break;
    }

    if (session.getVideoTrack()!=null) {
        VideoStream video = session.getVideoTrack();
        video.setFlashState(mFlash);
        video.setVideoQuality(mVideoQuality);
        video.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
        video.setPreviewOrientation(mOrientation);
        video.setDestinationPorts(5006);
    }

    if (session.getAudioTrack()!=null) {
        AudioStream audio = session.getAudioTrack();
        audio.setAudioQuality(mAudioQuality);
        audio.setDestinationPorts(5004);
    }

    return session;

}

/** 
 * Access to the context is needed for the H264Stream class to store some stuff in the SharedPreferences.
 * Note that you should pass the Application context, not the context of an Activity.
 **/
public SessionBuilder setContext(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    return this;
}

/** Sets the destination of the session. */
public SessionBuilder setDestination(String destination) {
    mDestination = destination;
    return this; 
}

/** Sets the origin of the session. It appears in the SDP of the session. */
public SessionBuilder setOrigin(String origin) {
    mOrigin = origin;
    return this;
}

/** Sets the video stream quality. */
public SessionBuilder setVideoQuality(VideoQuality quality) {
    mVideoQuality = quality.clone();
    return this;
}

/** Sets the audio encoder. */
public SessionBuilder setAudioEncoder(int encoder) {
    mAudioEncoder = encoder;
    return this;
}

/** Sets the audio quality. */
public SessionBuilder setAudioQuality(AudioQuality quality) {
    mAudioQuality = quality.clone();
    return this;
}

/** Sets the default video encoder. */
public SessionBuilder setVideoEncoder(int encoder) {
    mVideoEncoder = encoder;
    return this;
}

public SessionBuilder setFlashEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mFlash = enabled;
    return this;
}

public SessionBuilder setCamera(int camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    return this;
}

public SessionBuilder setTimeToLive(int ttl) {
    mTimeToLive = ttl;
    return this;
}

/** 
 * Sets the SurfaceView required to preview the video stream. 
 **/
public SessionBuilder setSurfaceView(SurfaceView surfaceView) {
    mSurfaceView = surfaceView;
    return this;
}

/** 
 * Sets the orientation of the preview.
 * @param orientation The orientation of the preview
 */
public SessionBuilder setPreviewOrientation(int orientation) {
    mOrientation = orientation;
    return this;
}   

public SessionBuilder setCallback(Session.Callback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
    return this;
}

/** Returns the context set with {@link #setContext(Context)}*/
public Context getContext() {
    return mContext;    
}

/** Returns the destination ip address set with {@link #setDestination(String)}. */
public String getDestination() {
    return mDestination;
}

/** Returns the origin ip address set with {@link #setOrigin(String)}. */
public String getOrigin() {
    return mOrigin;
}

/** Returns the audio encoder set with {@link #setAudioEncoder(int)}. */
public int getAudioEncoder() {
    return mAudioEncoder;
}

/** Returns the id of the {@link android.hardware.Camera} set with {@link #setCamera(int)}. */
public int getCamera() {
    return mCamera;
}

/** Returns the video encoder set with {@link #setVideoEncoder(int)}. */
public int getVideoEncoder() {
    return mVideoEncoder;
}

/** Returns the VideoQuality set with {@link #setVideoQuality(VideoQuality)}. */
public VideoQuality getVideoQuality() {
    return mVideoQuality;
}

/** Returns the AudioQuality set with {@link #setAudioQuality(AudioQuality)}. */
public AudioQuality getAudioQuality() {
    return mAudioQuality;
}

/** Returns the flash state set with {@link #setFlashEnabled(boolean)}. */
public boolean getFlashState() {
    return mFlash;
}

/** Returns the SurfaceView set with {@link #setSurfaceView(SurfaceView)}. */
public SurfaceView getSurfaceView() {
    return mSurfaceView;
}


/** Returns the time to live set with {@link #setTimeToLive(int)}. */
public int getTimeToLive() {
    return mTimeToLive;
}

/** Returns a new {@link SessionBuilder} with the same configuration. */
public SessionBuilder clone() {
    return new SessionBuilder()
    .setDestination(mDestination)
    .setOrigin(mOrigin)
    .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
    .setPreviewOrientation(mOrientation)
    .setVideoQuality(mVideoQuality)
    .setVideoEncoder(mVideoEncoder)
    .setFlashEnabled(mFlash)
    .setCamera(mCamera)
    .setTimeToLive(mTimeToLive)
    .setAudioEncoder(mAudioEncoder)
    .setAudioQuality(mAudioQuality)
    .setContext(mContext)
    .setCallback(mCallback);
}

}
```

Session Class:

```
public class Session {

public final static String TAG = "Session";

public final static int STREAM_VIDEO = 0x01;

public final static int STREAM_AUDIO = 0x00;

/** Some app is already using a camera (Camera.open() has failed). */
public final static int ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE = 0x00;

/** The phone may not support some streaming parameters that you are trying to use (bit rate, frame rate, resolution...). */
public final static int ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED = 0x01;

/** 
 * The internal storage of the phone is not ready. 
 * libstreaming tried to store a test file on the sdcard but couldn't.
 * See H264Stream and AACStream to find out why libstreaming would want to something like that. 
 */
public final static int ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY = 0x02;

/** The phone has no flash. */
public final static int ERROR_CAMERA_HAS_NO_FLASH = 0x03;

/** The supplied SurfaceView is not a valid surface, or has not been created yet. */
public final static int ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE = 0x04;

/** 
 * The destination set with {@link Session#setDestination(String)} could not be resolved. 
 * May mean that the phone has no access to the internet, or that the DNS server could not
 * resolved the host name.
 */
public final static int ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST = 0x05;

/**
 * Some other error occurred !
 */
public final static int ERROR_OTHER = 0x06;

private String mOrigin;
private String mDestination;
private int mTimeToLive = 64;
private long mTimestamp;

private AudioStream mAudioStream = null;
private VideoStream mVideoStream = null;

private Callback mCallback;
private Handler mMainHandler;

private Handler mHandler;

/** 
 * Creates a streaming session that can be customized by adding tracks.
 */
public Session() {
    long uptime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session");
    thread.start();

    mHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
    mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mTimestamp = (uptime/1000)<<32 & (((uptime-((uptime/1000)*1000))>>32)/1000); // NTP timestamp
    mOrigin = "127.0.0.1";
}

/**
 * The callback interface you need to implement to get some feedback
 * Those will be called from the UI thread.
 */
public interface Callback {

    /** 
     * Called periodically to inform you on the bandwidth 
     * consumption of the streams when streaming. 
     */
    public void onBitrateUpdate(long bitrate);

    /** Called when some error occurs. */
    public void onSessionError(int reason, int streamType, Exception e);

    /** 
     * Called when the previw of the {@link VideoStream}
     * has correctly been started.
     * If an error occurs while starting the preview,
     * {@link Callback#onSessionError(int, int, Exception)} will be
     * called instead of {@link Callback#onPreviewStarted()}.
     */
    public void onPreviewStarted();

    /** 
     * Called when the session has correctly been configured 
     * after calling {@link Session#configure()}.
     * If an error occurs while configuring the {@link Session},
     * {@link Callback#onSessionError(int, int, Exception)} will be
     * called instead of  {@link Callback#onSessionConfigured()}.
     */
    public void onSessionConfigured();

    /** 
     * Called when the streams of the session have correctly been started.
     * If an error occurs while starting the {@link Session},
     * {@link Callback#onSessionError(int, int, Exception)} will be
     * called instead of  {@link Callback#onSessionStarted()}. 
     */
    public void onSessionStarted();

    /** Called when the stream of the session have been stopped. */
    public void onSessionStopped();

}

/** You probably don't need to use that directly, use the {@link SessionBuilder}. */
void addAudioTrack(AudioStream track) {
    removeAudioTrack();
    mAudioStream = track;
}

/** You probably don't need to use that directly, use the {@link SessionBuilder}. */
void addVideoTrack(VideoStream track) {
    removeVideoTrack();
    mVideoStream = track;
}

/** You probably don't need to use that directly, use the {@link SessionBuilder}. */
void removeAudioTrack() {
    if (mAudioStream != null) {
        mAudioStream.stop();
        mAudioStream = null;
    }
}

/** You probably don't need to use that directly, use the {@link SessionBuilder}. */
void removeVideoTrack() {
    if (mVideoStream != null) {
        mVideoStream.stopPreview();
        mVideoStream = null;
    }
}

/** Returns the underlying {@link AudioStream} used by the {@link Session}. */
public AudioStream getAudioTrack() {
    return mAudioStream;
}

/** Returns the underlying {@link VideoStream} used by the {@link Session}. */
public VideoStream getVideoTrack() {
    return mVideoStream;
}   

/**
 * Sets the callback interface that will be called by the {@link Session}.
 * @param callback The implementation of the {@link Callback} interface
 */
public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}   

/** 
 * The origin address of the session.
 * It appears in the session description.
 * @param origin The origin address
 */
public void setOrigin(String origin) {
    mOrigin = origin;
}   

/** 
 * The destination address for all the streams of the session. <br />
 * Changes will be taken into account the next time you start the session.
 * @param destination The destination address
 */
public void setDestination(String destination) {
    mDestination =  destination;
}

/** 
 * Set the TTL of all packets sent during the session. <br />
 * Changes will be taken into account the next time you start the session.
 * @param ttl The Time To Live
 */
public void setTimeToLive(int ttl) {
    mTimeToLive = ttl;
}

/** 
 * Sets the configuration of the stream. <br />
 * You can call this method at any time and changes will take 
 * effect next time you call {@link #configure()}.
 * @param quality Quality of the stream
 */
public void setVideoQuality(VideoQuality quality) {
    if (mVideoStream != null) {
        mVideoStream.setVideoQuality(quality);
    }
}

/**
 * Sets a Surface to show a preview of recorded media (video). <br />
 * You can call this method at any time and changes will take 
 * effect next time you call {@link #start()} or {@link #startPreview()}.
 */
public void setSurfaceView(final SurfaceView view) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mVideoStream != null) {
                mVideoStream.setSurfaceView(view);
            }
        }               
    });
}

/** 
 * Sets the orientation of the preview. <br />
 * You can call this method at any time and changes will take 
 * effect next time you call {@link #configure()}.
 * @param orientation The orientation of the preview
 */
public void setPreviewOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (mVideoStream != null) {
        mVideoStream.setPreviewOrientation(orientation);
    }
}   

/** 
 * Sets the configuration of the stream. <br />
 * You can call this method at any time and changes will take 
 * effect next time you call {@link #configure()}.
 * @param quality Quality of the stream
 */
public void setAudioQuality(AudioQuality quality) {
    if (mAudioStream != null) {
        mAudioStream.setAudioQuality(quality);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the {@link Callback} interface that was set with 
 * {@link #setCallback(Callback)} or null if none was set.
 */
public Callback getCallback() {
    return mCallback;
}   

/** 
 * Returns a Session Description that can be stored in a file or sent to a client with RTSP.
 * @return The Session Description.
 * @throws IllegalStateException Thrown when {@link #setDestination(String)} has never been called.
 */
public String getSessionDescription() {
    StringBuilder sessionDescription = new StringBuilder();
    if (mDestination==null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("setDestination() has not been called !");
    }
    sessionDescription.append("v=0\r\n");
    // TODO: Add IPV6 support
    sessionDescription.append("o=- "+mTimestamp+" "+mTimestamp+" IN IP4 "+mOrigin+"\r\n");
    sessionDescription.append("s=Unnamed\r\n");
    sessionDescription.append("i=N/A\r\n");
    sessionDescription.append("c=IN IP4 "+mDestination+"\r\n");
    // t=0 0 means the session is permanent (we don't know when it will stop)
    sessionDescription.append("t=0 0\r\n");
    sessionDescription.append("a=recvonly\r\n");
    // Prevents two different sessions from using the same peripheral at the same time
    if (mAudioStream != null) {
        sessionDescription.append(mAudioStream.getSessionDescription());
        sessionDescription.append("a=control:trackID="+0+"\r\n");
    }
    if (mVideoStream != null) {
        sessionDescription.append(mVideoStream.getSessionDescription());
        sessionDescription.append("a=control:trackID="+1+"\r\n");
    }           
    return sessionDescription.toString();
}

/** Returns the destination set with {@link #setDestination(String)}. */
public String getDestination() {
    return mDestination;
}

/** Returns an approximation of the bandwidth consumed by the session in bit per second. */
public long getBitrate() {
    long sum = 0;
    if (mAudioStream != null) sum += mAudioStream.getBitrate();
    if (mVideoStream != null) sum += mVideoStream.getBitrate();
    return sum;
}

/** Indicates if a track is currently running. */
public boolean isStreaming() {
    if ( (mAudioStream!=null && mAudioStream.isStreaming()) || (mVideoStream!=null && mVideoStream.isStreaming()) )
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

/** 
 * Configures all streams of the session.
 **/
public void configure() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                syncConfigure();
            } catch (Exception e) {};
        }
    });
}   

/** 
 * Does the same thing as {@link #configure()}, but in a synchronous manner. <br />
 * Throws exceptions in addition to calling a callback 
 * {@link Callback#onSessionError(int, int, Exception)} when
 * an error occurs. 
 **/
public void syncConfigure()  
        throws CameraInUseException, 
        StorageUnavailableException,
        ConfNotSupportedException, 
        InvalidSurfaceException, 
        RuntimeException,
        IOException {

    for (int id=0;id<2;id++) {
        Stream stream = id==0 ? mAudioStream : mVideoStream;
        if (stream!=null && !stream.isStreaming()) {
            try {
                stream.configure();
            } catch (CameraInUseException e) {
                postError(ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE , id, e);
                throw e;
            } catch (StorageUnavailableException e) {
                postError(ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY , id, e);
                throw e;
            } catch (ConfNotSupportedException e) {
                postError(ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED , id, e);
                throw e;
            } catch (InvalidSurfaceException e) {
                postError(ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE , id, e);
                throw e;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                postError(ERROR_OTHER, id, e);
                throw e;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                postError(ERROR_OTHER, id, e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    postSessionConfigured();
}

/** 
 * Asynchronously starts all streams of the session.
 **/
public void start() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                syncStart();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }               
    });
}

/** 
 * Starts a stream in a synchronous manner. <br />
 * Throws exceptions in addition to calling a callback.
 * @param id The id of the stream to start
 **/
public void syncStart(int id)           
        throws CameraInUseException, 
        StorageUnavailableException,
        ConfNotSupportedException, 
        InvalidSurfaceException, 
        UnknownHostException,
        IOException {

    Stream stream = id==0 ? mAudioStream : mVideoStream;
    if (stream!=null && !stream.isStreaming()) {
        try {
            InetAddress destination =  InetAddress.getByName(mDestination);
            stream.setTimeToLive(mTimeToLive);
            stream.setDestinationAddress(destination);
            stream.start();
            if (getTrack(1-id) == null || getTrack(1-id).isStreaming()) {
                postSessionStarted();
            }
            if (getTrack(1-id) == null || !getTrack(1-id).isStreaming()) {
                mHandler.post(mUpdateBitrate);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            postError(ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST, id, e);
            throw e;
        } catch (CameraInUseException e) {
            postError(ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE , id, e);
            throw e;
        } catch (StorageUnavailableException e) {
            postError(ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY , id, e);
            throw e;
        } catch (ConfNotSupportedException e) {
            postError(ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED , id, e);
            throw e;
        } catch (InvalidSurfaceException e) {
            postError(ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE , id, e);
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            postError(ERROR_OTHER, id, e);
            throw e;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            postError(ERROR_OTHER, id, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

}   

/** 
 * Does the same thing as {@link #start()}, but in a synchronous manner. <br /> 
 * Throws exceptions in addition to calling a callback.
 **/
public void syncStart()             
        throws CameraInUseException, 
        StorageUnavailableException,
        ConfNotSupportedException, 
        InvalidSurfaceException, 
        UnknownHostException,
        IOException {

    syncStart(1);
    try {
        syncStart(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        syncStop(1);
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        syncStop(1);
        throw e;
    }

}   

/** Stops all existing streams. */
public void stop() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            syncStop();
        }
    });
}

/** 
 * Stops one stream in a synchronous manner.
 * @param id The id of the stream to stop
 **/    
private void syncStop(final int id) {
    Stream stream = id==0 ? mAudioStream : mVideoStream;
    if (stream!=null) {
        stream.stop();
    }
}       

/** Stops all existing streams in a synchronous manner. */
public void syncStop() {
    syncStop(0);
    syncStop(1);
    postSessionStopped();
}

/**
 * Asynchronously starts the camera preview. <br />
 * You should of course pass a {@link SurfaceView} to {@link #setSurfaceView(SurfaceView)}
 * before calling this method. Otherwise, the {@link Callback#onSessionError(int, int, Exception)}
 * callback will be called with {@link #ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE}.
 */
public void startPreview() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mVideoStream != null) {
                try {
                    mVideoStream.startPreview();
                    postPreviewStarted();
                    mVideoStream.configure();
                } catch (CameraInUseException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE , STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (ConfNotSupportedException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED , STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (InvalidSurfaceException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE , STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_OTHER, STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (StorageUnavailableException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY, STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_OTHER, STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Asynchronously stops the camera preview.
 */
public void stopPreview() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mVideoStream != null) {
                mVideoStream.stopPreview();
            }
        }
    });
}   

/** Switch between the front facing and the back facing camera of the phone. <br />
 * If {@link #startPreview()} has been called, the preview will be  briefly interrupted. <br />
 * If {@link #start()} has been called, the stream will be  briefly interrupted.<br />
 * To find out which camera is currently selected, use {@link #getCamera()}
 **/
public void switchCamera() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mVideoStream != null) {
                try {
                    mVideoStream.switchCamera();
                    postPreviewStarted();
                } catch (CameraInUseException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE , STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (ConfNotSupportedException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED , STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (InvalidSurfaceException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE , STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_OTHER, STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_OTHER, STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Returns the id of the camera currently selected. <br />
 * It can be either {@link CameraInfo#CAMERA_FACING_BACK} or 
 * {@link CameraInfo#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT}.
 */
public int getCamera() {
    return mVideoStream != null ? mVideoStream.getCamera() : 0;

}

/** 
 * Toggles the LED of the phone if it has one.
 * You can get the current state of the flash with 
 * {@link Session#getVideoTrack()} and {@link VideoStream#getFlashState()}.
 **/
public void toggleFlash() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mVideoStream != null) {
                try {
                    mVideoStream.toggleFlash();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    postError(ERROR_CAMERA_HAS_NO_FLASH, STREAM_VIDEO, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}   

/** Deletes all existing tracks & release associated resources. */
public void release() {
    removeAudioTrack();
    removeVideoTrack();
    mHandler.getLooper().quit();
}

private void postPreviewStarted() {
    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onPreviewStarted(); 
            }
        }
    });
}

private void postSessionConfigured() {
    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onSessionConfigured(); 
            }
        }
    });
}

private void postSessionStarted() {
    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onSessionStarted(); 
            }
        }
    });
}       

private void postSessionStopped() {
    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onSessionStopped(); 
            }
        }
    });
}   

private void postError(final int reason, final int streamType,final Exception e) {
    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onSessionError(reason, streamType, e); 
            }
        }
    });
}   

private void postBitRate(final long bitrate) {
    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onBitrateUpdate(bitrate);
            }
        }
    });
}       

private Runnable mUpdateBitrate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isStreaming()) { 
            postBitRate(getBitrate());
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateBitrate, 500);
        } else {
            postBitRate(0);
        }
    }
};


public boolean trackExists(int id) {
    if (id==0) 
        return mAudioStream!=null;
    else
        return mVideoStream!=null;
}

public Stream getTrack(int id) {
    if (id==0)
        return mAudioStream;
    else
        return mVideoStream;
}

}
```

Comment: can you share your code which contains the session builder and the server?

Comment: @KhalilM updated post, I can not post all classes in the post , the code is the same of example in the link only we change Wowza server with our server and the connection is OK, Audio is streaming and working ok but the video is received 0 for input stream file